# Generated classes

Tags: flutter, design-patterns

I try to sync data via GraphQL from my backend. Therefore I use the artemis package to generate my classes. However I then want to cache the data localy and therefore use the sqfentity_gen package to generate classes to safe my data via sql. I can use a json constructor with each framework to convert the data between.However I want to encapsulate certain functionality since I dont want to just safe changed data localy but sync it to the backend and handle certain errors like merge conflicts or missing network. Therefore I am thinking about wrapping the classes with an other one since I cant change the generated code. Is this a good idea or are there other solutions which work better? Would you use a completly diffrent setup? Glad for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generate and/or re-generate (update) classes which are based on db-tables (I assume), you can use solution from the box, in example, [NReco.GraphQL](https://www.nrecosite.com/graphql_to_sql_database.aspx)
It allows you set db-schema in the json file and just set db-connection. If you have a lot of tables, you can just generate that json file based on metatable info.

Storing and updating classes, from my point of view is useless.